# How to tackle Big O proofs that involve multiple parameters

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I am getting more and more familiar with the whole concept of time complexity but I have never encountered an example where more than one parameter is involved. Therefore, is it possible(well, I am sure it is :")) and how to prove

> a^n = Θ(logn)

or any other, similar-looking expression?

> c1 * logn ≤ a^n ≤ c2 * logn

where, e.g. c1 = 1 and c2 = 2,

> logn ≤ a^n ≤2 * logn.

Can I go one step further and set n, to be equal e.g. 2? This way I will get

> log(2) ≤ a^2 ≤ log(4)

Which is surely true(for a between ~ 0.55 and 0.77)...

...but isn't that too specific and interfere with the inequality too much? Sorry if the answer is trivial but Google is not helping and I have nobody to ask for explanation.

Comment: If a, b, c are constants, proofs don't change a whole lot. Normal rules apply.

Comment: Your inequations are all wrong !

Answer (score 0):

That isn't true. As you say, it implies there are $c_2$ and $N$ so that for all $n \ge N$ you have $a^n \le c_2 \log n$. Consider:

$\begin{align*}
  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^n}{\log n}
      &= \lim_{n \to \infty}
                \frac{a^n \log a}{1 / n}
      = \infty
\end{align*}$

Here we used l'Hôpital. But that the limit is infinite means that eventually the ratio is larger than any given $c_2$. In fact, it proves $a^n = \Omega(\log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your example shows two "parameters", but only one is the variable of interest ($n$, usually denoting the problem *size*).

Unfortunately, your example is not really suitable for an explanation, as only

$$a^n=\Theta(a^n)$$ can be shown to hold, and this is trivial. [$a^n=\Theta(\log n)$ is just wrong.]

For a less trivial parametric example, consider

$$(n+a)^3=\Theta(n^3).$$

Indeed,

$$\frac{(n+a)^3}{n^3}=1+3\frac an+3\frac{a^2}{n^2}+\frac{a^3}{n^3}$$ and by taking $n\gg|a|$ you can make the last three terms as small as you want. E.g., take $n>10|a|$ and

$$1-0.3+0.03-0.001=0.729<\frac{(n+a)^3}{n^3}<1+0.3+0.03+0.001=1.331$$